# I can't login using Google and it redirects to login page instead of index page

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm working on a simple personal project that will let user to sign in using google account using Google GSI library OAauth 2.0. I explore the document on how to use the GSI library and implement it on my code.

The process is this: after user select account in Google Sign In, the email will be checked (google_signin.php) if already exist in the database. If true, proceed to creating session and redirecting the user to index.php. The problem is after selecting a google account, it only redirects to login.php instead of index.php and creating a session.

The files are: login.php, google_signin.php (for checking the email), index.php (where user mus redirect after logging in).

Here is the code

```
<script>
    function onSignIn(response) {
        const { id_token, access_token, email } = response.credential; // Include email in response

        fetch('google_signin.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id_token, access_token, email }), // Include email in JSON
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                // User's email address is valid, create a session and log them in
                // Implement your session creation and login logic here
                console.log('User is authenticated and can be logged in.');
                // You can redirect to index.php here
                // window.location.href = 'index.php';
            } else {
                // Display an error message or prompt the user to create a new account
                console.error('User email address not found in the database:', email);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Server verification failed:', error);
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="34178471422-5chptlf4ujd05p5a6suhvglmcc2f9jgk.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-callback="onSignIn"
     data-auto_prompt="false"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost/public_html/index.php">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

Here is the google_signin (PHP Code) https://pastecode.io/s/to2n4d0u

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: be aware that your pastecode snippet holds a sql injection issue

Answer (score 1):

in your onSignIn function your are calling fetch which is a async function call, should you not wait (async function with await fetch)on the result before returning the function?

```
function async onSignIn(response) {

    await fetch('google_signin.php', {...})
}
```

Comment: what will be the possible solution to that?